# Am trying to use a font awesome icon as a button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Am trying to use a font awesome icon as a button to implement the like feature in my web application, using bootstrap 4 and font awesome

```
<button class="icon-button" onclick="actOnStory(event);"data-story-id="<%= story._id %>">
     <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

my current code results in the icon being inside the button and not being the button itself

Comment: HI! Could you give more information about your code and how it looks so we could help you better? Like the entire file or the sections that you think are wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to tweak the class `icon-button` to fit your purpose. By default the icon is supposed to be rendered within the button, but you can pad the button and let the icon be in the center of it. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_icon_buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to wrap `<i>` with `<button>`, since `onclick` event can be called on icon as well. Just make it

```
<i class="far fa-heart" onclick="actOnStory(event);" data-story-id="<%= story._id %>"></i>
```

Comment: Could you point out how this is different from the already existing answer?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: welcome to SO @Blessed. Here is something to get you started here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow